# How to check if the ajax call for jQuery DataTable has returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to load the jQuery DataTable from an AJAX call as in the code below. However I need to know if there is a callback for the DataTable to check if the AJAX call returned successfully or failed before the table is loaded.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#data-table').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    responsive: true,
    serverSide: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    paging: true,
    filter: true,
    searching: true,
    stateSave: true,
    scrollX: true,
    lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
      type: 'GET',
      dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [{
      title: 'Zone',
      data: 'LastKnownZone',
    }, {
      title: 'Hiérarchie Map',
      data: 'MapInfo.mapHierarchyString',
    }, {
      title: 'Addresse MAC',
      data: 'macAddress',
    }],
    initComplete: function(json) {
      let returned_data = json;
      //..Do something with data returned
    }
  });
});
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding something to @Fawaz Ibrahim's answer, it's also better to add error option in Ajax call in order to check if you face any error or problem , because in case of error, dataSrc callback won't run, so you won't have any successful returned data.

```
ajax: {
  ...
  dataSrc: function ( receivedData ) {
    console.log('The data has arrived'); // Here you can know that the data has been received
    return receivedData;
  },  
 error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
     console.log('here you can track the error');
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate mate

Comment: In your code of error handling did you meand `error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){...}` ?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This helped me very much. The only thing that I had to add was the name of my internal (Java-/JSON-) List in order to get displayed: `return receivedData.listFromJson`

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned on their official site:

> For completeness of our Ajax loading discussion, it is worth stating
>   that at this time DataTables unfortunately does not support
>   configuration via Ajax. This is something that will be reviewed in
>   future

But you can use the idea of datasrc, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#data-table').DataTable({
    ...
    ajax: {
      ...
      dataSrc: function ( receivedData ) {
        console.log('The data has arrived'); // Here you can know that the data has been received
        return receivedData;
      }
    },
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: What if data has not arrived, can u put the if statement inside the dataSrc ? something like this `if(receivedData){ //do something } else { return;}` Appreciate the help

Comment: No, as i noticed this code will be executed just in case the Ajax succeed